# Manually calling the destructor for statically allocated variables

Tags: c++

```
void func( int x )
{
    char* pleak = new char[1024]; // might be lost => memory leak
    std::string s( "hello world" ); // will be properly destructed

    if ( x ) throw std::runtime_error( "boom" );

    delete [] pleak; // will only get here if x == 0. if x!=0, throw exception
}
```

For the above code, s is destroyed at the end of the function scope.
Is it possible to manually call the destructor on the object std::string?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Break your program?

Comment: Just to learn....

Comment: Learn what exactly? And where do statically allocated variables come in?

Comment: Learn if there is such a feature that can unwind the stack manually

Comment: Calling a destructor does not unwind the stack. Unwinding the stack calls the destructors of local variables, but not vice versa (that would be an infinite loop).

Comment: This process of destroying local objects and calling destructors is called stack unwinding.

Comment: No, that's not what I call it.

Comment: The only time I know of where it makes sense to manually call the destructor is when using placement new.

Comment: I see no statics in this code whatsoever; only automatic and dynamic.

Comment: `std::string::~string()` *is* called automatically even when you throw an exception.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to manually call the destructor on the object std::string?

Technically yes, it is possible to call the destructor of an automatic variable. But if the execution leaves the scope that has a destroyed automatic variable, the behaviour of the program would be undefined, so doing this is of little use in practice. You don't want your program to have undefined behaviour.

Explicit call to destructor is typically used when you've reused storage (typically an array of `char` or `std::byte`) for an object or array of objects using the placement-new expression.

> Hows to do this?

You call the destructor just like you would call a member function. The name of the destructor is `~T` for a class named `T`. In the particular case of `std::string` and other type aliases within a namespace, you need to do some gymnastics to get around grammar limitations. All of below are correct:

```
s.std::string::~string();

s.~basic_string();

using std::string;
s.~string();
```

---

P.S. `s` has automatic storage, not static.

Comment: Hows to do this?

Comment: @user10713170 You first: *why* do this ? You're not using placement-new, which frankly is the only time one really has cause to manually fire destructors (in fact, it's required if placement new is done correctly). If your answer is "to learn", to learn *what* ?

Comment: As @eerorika said, if you do it, your program behavior is undefined. It usually crashes.

Comment: `(&s)->~std::string();`. But again: Don't do it. There's no valid reason to EVER do this to a class that you didn't create with placement-new

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher `It usually crashes` If you're lucky :)

Comment: @MooingDuck `(&foo)->` is a weird way to write `foo.`.

Comment: Indeed, if you are lucky.

Comment: @melpomene I vaguely recall working with a compiler that considered `foo.~std::string();` to be an error, so I had to do it through a pointer. Or maybe I'm misremembering.

Comment: @MooingDuck Not sure about the indirection, but I think the syntax should be `foo.std::string::~string()` or `foo.~basic_string()` to get the correct name lookup.

Comment: @user10605163 good point about name lookup. I've added your examples and one another to the answer since it's not obvious.

Comment: @user10713170 -- Let me say this -- you will hardly ever, if ever, run into a case where you need to do this.  Spend time learning C++ that is most often used, not the esoteric parts of the language that are only used *properly* by seasoned professionals and/or advanced C++ programmers.